# AngularJs ui-router controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have an issues of assigning controller using `angular-ui-router`. Following is what I have:

Routing:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$controllerProvider', '$compileProvider', '$filterProvider', '$provide', '$ocLazyLoadProvider', 'JS_REQUIRES','$authProvider',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide, $ocLazyLoadProvider, jsRequires,$authProvider) {

    app.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
    app.directive = $compileProvider.directive;
    app.filter = $filterProvider.register;
    app.factory = $provide.factory;
    app.service = $provide.service;
    app.constant = $provide.constant;
    app.value = $provide.value;


    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
        debug: false,
        events: true,
        modules: jsRequires.modules
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/app/dashboard");
    $stateProvider.state('app.yourbooking',{
    url: "/booking",
    templateUrl: "assets/views/booking.html",
    title:"Your Bookings",
    controller: "BookingCtrl",
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: 'Your Bookings'
     }
   })
```

Controller:

```
'use strict';


    app.controller('BookingCtrl', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {

            $scope.name = "Hitler";

    }]);
```

And View:

```
<div ng-controller="BookingCtrl">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-wide btn-primary" ng-click="damm()">
                Primary
            </button>
</div>
```

But I receiving an error on console:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/ng/areq?p0=BookongCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
```

There is similar setup on others controller, but there is no issues with it. When I create a new controller for a new page, I getting the above error. This is actually Clip-Two admin theme from `http://themeforest.net/item/cliptwo-bootstrap-admin-template-with-angularjs/10290688`

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you missing a `}]);` at the end of the first block of code?

Comment: no i cut short the code

Comment: `$scope.name = "Hitler";` really?

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch between controller names in view and script

`BookongCtrl` vs `BookingCtrl`

View version has typo

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem then. How can it be same error when the one shown shows the incorrect name?

Comment: I work out on reverse where I track where the error began. It start when I declare controller on router. Just a controller, does it suppose to behave in norm conditions?

Comment: again...create a demo in plunker that replicates problem